# Building metallib with CMake

Tags: cmake, metal, metalkit

I have some `.metal` files and I want to compile it to `.metallib`. Whole build system is using CMake and I am going to use it to compile `.metal` too.

To build .metallib I must use the next two commands:

```
xcrun -sdk macosx metal -c MyLibrary.metal -o MyLibrary.air
xcrun -sdk macosx metallib MyLibrary.air -o MyLibrary.metallib
```

Is there any convenient way to do it with CMake where I can set compiler and CMake will do everything automatically? Or I should use `add_custom_command` and manually call `xcrun`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Both approaches, using custom commands/targets and adding a new language, are valid. The choice seems to depend on trade-offs between reusability, distribution range, target users, etc. Personally, I'd initially opt for the former.

---

Having said that, if you opt for the [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html)/[`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) method, it can get you pretty far. Just make sure that you provide actual targets and link them with the `OUTPUT` of custom commands, in order to be able to set up proper dependencies and avoiding unnecessary re-execution of targets when dependencies are still up to date. For example,

```
set(FOO_FILE "foo.txt")

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${FOO_FILE}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${FOO_FILE}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
  COMMENT "Creating ${FOO_FILE}"
  VERBATIM)

add_custom_target(foo DEPENDS ${FOO_FILE})
```

The approach of adding a new language is a bit more involved, as it's targeted to be more generic and provide language support as a CMake feature (i.e. not tied to a particular project). For this, you are required to define various aspects of the language, such as the compiler and the rules to use to process the source files. Apart, from these, feature detection and testing usually fall here too. For more detailed documentation have a look [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeAddNewLanguage.txt).

However, investigating an actual language as is supported by CMake could be helpful. I'd suggest having a look under CMake's `Modules` directory for CUDA (this will lead you to have a look into the `Compiler` and `Platform` subdirs too).

**NOTE**: Digging through the mailing list, I bumped into this [thread](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-March/043444.html), that mentions that the second approach might not work so well with non Makefile-based generators. It is not clear from the thread (or the existing documentation) and I cannot try it since I'm not using CMake via such a tool (e.g. MSVC or Xcode).

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target`. For every `.metal` file I set `add_custom_command` for creating `.air`. And then I define custom command for creating `.metallib`.

Answer (score -1):

```
# metal kernel
set(SRC_METAL_KERNEL
  "src/rgb2bgr.metal"
  "src/yuv2rgb.metal"
)
set_source_files_properties(${SRC_METAL_KERNEL} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE METAL)

# set metal version
if(TARGETOS STREQUAL "mac")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=macos-metal2.0")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=macos-metal2.0")
else()
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=ios-metal2.0")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=ios-metal2.0")
endif()

add_library(MetalLibary STATIC ${SRC_METAL_KERNEL})

set(ADDITIONAL_LINKER_FLAGS "-framework Metal -framework MetalPerformanceShaders")
target_link_libraries(MetalLibary ${ADDITIONAL_LINKER_FLAGS})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).